How to import a texture/image asset within a JS file when using Symfony with assetmapper?
I'm trying to implement ThreeJS 3D animation on my Symfony + Assetmapper application. Displaying assets in the twig templates works fine and I was able to get a simple background animation running.
The problem is that I am now trying to use a custom fragment shader for one of my 3D objects and I want to import an image in my ThreeJS script so I can pass it into the Shader Material as a uniform.
I tried manually adding:

an absolute path to the texture
relative path
path to the versioned texture

like this:
// base.html.twig
<script type="module" src="{{ asset('scripts/three.js') }}"></script>

// three.js

  uniforms = {
    ...
    uTexture: { value: new THREE.TextureLoader('assets/images/texture.webp') }
  };


The issue here is that I do not know how to get assetmapper to correctly map this asset to its versioned equivalent. Right now I cannot find a way to even load the texture by supplying the current versioned name.
Here is a log of uniform:
ThreeJS uniform with manual texture path

Have you tried set image path relative to the current javascript file, for example: new THREE.TextureLoader('../images/textura.wep');

@Francisco Yes, that did not work.
